# Printing a timeline, logistic issue

Tags: python, printing, python-2.7

I have a dict. Keys are numbers between 0 and 60. Which is minutes. Examplary dict looks like this:

```
{u'31': 1, u'2': 0, u'30': 1}
```

I want to print the keys (numbers) as a timeline with hyphens among all the keys, everything comma separated. Number of hyphens is indicated by the number of each key from the dict.

Net result should be:

```
-,-,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,1,1,-,-,-,-,-,-
```

(this above is just for illustration, number of hyphens inbetween is not correct, but you got the picture. This means that at position `2` (dict's key), there's `0` (dict's value), at position `30` there is the value of `1` and so on).

I have this code

```
for k, v in time_events.iteritems():
    print '-,'*int(k) + str(v)+',',
```

but this would result in

```
-,-,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,1,-,-,-,-,-,-,-1
```

it prints every event as separate timeline (so there'll be 30 hyphens between `30` and `31` and should be none)

My guess is, to first order the dict by keys then substract the previous key number  from the currect key, which would give the remaining number of hyphens yet to print inbetween numbers. But how to actually access the `previous key` in my `for` loop?

Hope my question in understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
>>> dct={u'31': 1, u'2': 0, u'30': 1}
>>> ','.join(str(dct.get(str(i), '-')) for i in range(60))
'-,-,0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,1,1,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'
```

`dct.get(str(i), '-')` basically tries to access `dct[str(i)]`. If it doesn't exist, it returns the second parameter (default value). [Here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) is the relevant documentation.